# How are these two sets equivalent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Given S = [0,1] and another set as R = {$$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{10^i} $$ } where $$a_1 \in {0,1,2,...,9}$$. Also the set R - {$$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{2^i} $$ } where $$a_1 \in {0,1}$$. My professor said these sets are same. How ?

Comment: Axiom of Extensionality: The three sets all have the same elements, so they are the all the same set. Or is the part that's troubling you whether those sets have the same elements?

Comment: yes how they have same element ?

Comment: like how do 0.998 can be written in terms of both R's ?

Comment: Treat it as 0.99800000...

Comment: You should use `$... $` instead of `$$... $$`

Answer (score 1):

Hint: these are representations of real numbers with radix 2 and radix 10, where [radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) is base of positional numeral system. For fractions are used negative degrees.

For example:
$$(0.678)_{10} = (0.1010110110010001011010000111001010110000 \cdots)_2$$
$$(0.998)_{10} = (0.1111111101111100111011011001000101101000 \cdots)_2$$

Comment: what is meaning of radix ?

Comment: and how do number say 0.678 be represented in radix 2 representation ?

Comment: @Jessica Griffin. Added to answer link and answer to your both question. General formula you can found also in Donald_E._Knuth_The_Art_of_Computer_Programming_v_2, p.195

Comment: $0.678=\frac6{10}+\frac7{100}+\frac8{1000}+\frac0{10000}+\ldots$, but also $0.678=\frac12+\frac18+\frac1{32}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{256}+\frac1{512}+\frac1{4096}+\ldots$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I understand how you have written when base is 10 which is based on places after decimal but how is that for base 2 ?

Comment: @zkutch - You're truncating the base-$2$ expansions. E.g., it should be $(0.678)_{10} =(0.10101101100100010110\ldots)_2$, with the ellipsis, since the base-$2$ expansion of this number doesn't terminate like it does in base-$10$. (It has a repeating cycle of length $102$, if I computed correctly.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Yes, you are right - I stopped in both cases at 20. Fixed. Thanks